# How to Retrieve a curl and Json value in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, json, curl

My jquery code is below, This is a currency converting through a API.In the API datas in json. I want to retrieve the data through AJax.

```
Im geting the error : Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\converter\ajax.php on line 25


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#currency").change(function(){
            var currency= $("#currency").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ajax.php", 
                cache: false,
                data: currency,
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    $("#quantity").keyup(function(){
                        //var local_rate= $("#local_rate").val();
                        var quantity= $("#quantity").val();
                        var us_rate= quantity / cur;
                        $('.listprice').html(us_rate);      
                    });
                }
            });


        });
    });
</script>
```

here is my php (ajax.php) code

```
<?php
$currency =$_GET['currency'];

$file = 'latest.json';
$appId = '306bdd0f71fe465280e48188846534af';

// Open CURL session:
$ch = curl_init("http://openexchangerates.org/api/{$file}?app_id={$appId}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Get the data:
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$exchangeRates = json_decode($json);

echo $rate= $exchangeRates->rates->$currency;

?>
```

Im stuck on retrieving the data, without using jquery its working perfectly... In here I want to load through Ajax..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `data: currency,` to `data: {currency: currency},` so the currency will be available  via `$_GET['currency']`

Comment: How can I gat the data as a variable without put into a alert?